# Can I use the Gps API of android freely?

Tags: android, gps

Good day, I just want to ask you guys, if I can just make a program utilizing the gps of android? Is the Gps, connects to satellite or any other devices out there, to be able to carry out its map tracking capability? If yes, is it free to be used even by a common indie developer?

Comment: You can use the GPS freely. If you use the Maps API, on the other hand, you have to follow [the terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPS (`LocationListener` using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`) is free in Android phones. Just that you need to add relevant permissions in your manifest.

If you are trying to use a map UI or using google maps (http://maps.googleapis.com), say for reverse geo-coding purpose, then you definitely have to pay subscriptions.

AFAIK, upto 2500 hits per day of the GOOGLE APIs is allowed from a single client for free without key purchase. If the hits exceed, automatically you would get "QUOTA VIOLATED FOR THE DAY" Exception. Beyond 2500 hits, if you want to use, you need to purchase the enterprise key from google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) It seems I have to monitor first if my app will hit above 2500